How to set GDM keyboard layout in Debian 12?
I am using the french bépo layout for my keyboard on a freshly installed Debian 12.
Everything is fine once I am logged in, but unfortunately the GDM login screen is using a qwerty layout.
How can I change it so it also uses the bépo layout ?
Here is my current configuration :
❯ cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT="fr"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBVARIANT="bepo_afnor"
XKBOPTIONS=""

❯ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "fr"
        Option "XkbVariant" "bepo_afnor"
EndSection

❯ localectl
System Locale: LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: fr
   X11 Layout: fr
    X11 Model: pc105
  X11 Variant: bepo_afnor

As you can see, I already tried solutions mentioned in another question (regarding Arch Linux), but without success.
Here are more information on my gdm and its configuration :

❯ /usr/sbin/gdm3 --version
GDM 43.0

❯ ls -al /etc/gdm3
total 48
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Oct 20 00:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 138 root root 12288 Oct 22 21:21 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   552 Oct 20 00:31 daemon.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1472 Jan 29  2023 greeter.dconf-defaults
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 22 21:01 Init
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 20 00:24 PostLogin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 18 15:44 PostSession
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 18 15:44 PreSession
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  5996 Jan 29  2023 Xsession

❯ ls -al /etc/gdm3/Init
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 22 21:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct 20 00:31 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2933 Oct 22 21:01 :1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2932 Oct 22 21:00 Default


search for "gdm configuration file" and "gdm configuration file debian login" in google

I already did that. Reading this https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en and trying different thing, my problem is that my gdm/Init/Default is not executed.

check for "/etc/gdm3/custom.conf" and check your permissions for /etc/gdm3/Init/Default set +x | https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/gdm3.8.html and https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-report/blob/master/internal/metrics/testdata/empty-fields/autologin/etc/gdm3/custom.conf

[daemon]
WaylandEnable=false
DefaultSession=gnome-xorg.desktop

How to use custom ~/.xsession with gdm3 | https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103722/how-to-use-custom-xsession-with-gdm3-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic

https://wiki.debian.org/Xsession

Thank you very much @Z0OM for the links. I'll look at them now with great caution. One of my problem is that I have gdm version 43.0 and the links says gdm3.8. I think I am missing something here, but can't spot what. As a side note, I updated my question with more information on my gdm configuration.

you use x or wayland, i see x in the q? echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE

How to use Wayland for the gdm login screen? | https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394962/how-to-use-wayland-for-the-gdm-login-screen

I am using X (x11 is the value of the XDG_SESSION_TYPE environment variable)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I will adjust that later in the day!
I'm now summarizing various sources of information. Some sources were not in English, so I translated them and/or presented them as block quotes.
Preliminary:
3 Parts Working Together for a Graphical Desktop Environment
Display Server Protocols
In the future, I would choose Wayland over X11 as display server protocols, and that's my opinion, because Wayland represents a more modern alternative that is more efficient and secure. However, Wayland still has its bugs.

GDM (GNOME Display Manager) will automatically use Wayland when supported, except when using the proprietary NVIDIA driver, in which case it will fall back to X11 due to instability.

Is X11 better than Wayland?

X11 vs. Wayland: A Linux Display Showdown The choice between X11 and
Wayland is a personal one, with no clear winner. X11 offers
tried-and-tested stability, flexibility, and wider application
compatibility. Wayland, on the other hand, shines with its smoother
visuals, better security, and potential for future innovation.

Display Managers:

GDM
LightDM
SDDM
LXDM
XDM
MDM
Qingy

Desktop Environments, these are some of the most commonly used desktop environments in Linux:

GNOME
KDE Plasma
Xfce
LXDE
LXQt
MATE
Cinnamon

From these 3 parts, you choose what works best together or harmonizes well.
My best experiences (only my):

Wayland, SDDM, KDE
X11, LightDM, Cinnamon
X11, LightDM, Xfce

I assume that your configuration is X11, GDM, and GNOME.
You could also try LightDM or SDDM and, as I mentioned, switch to Wayland.
How to use Wayland for the gdm login screen?
Possible Solutions:
1. GRUB
What I wouldn't try at all is changing the layout in GRUB, as GRUB only affects the keyboard layout during the boot phase and not on the GDM login screen. However, you can give it a try.
2. Debug, Logs, Errors
What you definitely need now is the debug mode and the logs to identify the sources of errors. What isn't clear from the question is whether /etc/gdm3/Init/Default is being executed and ignored or if it isn't executed at all.

gdm3 debug mode
journalctl gdm debug
gdm layout change log debugging
gmd logs
gdm journalctl
gdm dmesg

Gnome Help Troubleshooting

If GDM is failing to work properly, it is always a good idea to include debug information. To enable debugging, set the debug/Enable key to true in the <etc>/gdm/custom.conf file and restart GDM.
Then use GDM to the point where it fails, and debug output will be sent to the system log file (<var>/log/messages or <var>/adm/messages depending on your Operating System).

Old posts:
gdm does not run /etc/gdm/Init/Default
Board Tip, Add Log Output for Verification:
To check if the Default script is actually being executed, add a simple logging line to the script.
For example, add something like the following at the beginning of the script:
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/Init/Default
#!/bin/sh
echo "GDM Init Default script executed at $(date)" >> /var/log/gdm-init.log
setxkbmap fr bepo_afnor

This will create an entry in /var/log/gdm-init.log when the script is executed.
Make sure the script is executable:
sudo chmod +x /etc/gdm3/Init/Default
Restart GDM:
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
Check if /var/log/gdm-init.log exists and if there are any entries.
Possible GDM Error Logs:
sudo journalctl -xe | grep gdm
sudo journalctl -u gdm3
sudo grep gdm /var/log/syslog
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
GDM Debug Logs:
If you have debugging enabled in /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf
[debug]
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
Enable = true

Debian Wiki GDM
dmesg
Useful for checking if there were any issues during the boot process that could affect GDM.
dmesg | grep -i gdm
dmesg | grep -i keyboard
dmesg | grep -i layout
GNOME/Debugging
Where the "g_debug" output in GDM source code?
3. GDM Configuration Files and Scripting Integration Points
Check Scripting Integration Points section.

GDM has a number of configuration interfaces. These include scripting integration points, daemon configuration, greeter configuration, general session settings, integration with gnome-settings-daemon configuration, and session configuration. These types of integration are described in detail below.

The GDM script integration points can be found in the <etc>/gdm/ directory:
Xsession
Init/
PostLogin/
PreSession/
PostSession/

How to use custom ~/.xsession with gdm3 in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic?
Xsession Debian Wiki
Configuration
greeter.dconf-defaults
Create or edit and add or modify the following
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
[org/gnome/desktop/input-sources]
sources=[('xkb', 'fr+bepo_afnor')]

sudo dconf update

Sometimes if you do changes to the keyboard layout it requires
updating the initramfs

sudo update-initramfs -u
If the script /etc/gdm3/Init/Default is not being executed, it suggests that GDM may not be invoking it, as this might vary depending on the system configuration or changes in newer GDM versions.
3. Use the custom.conf
Try adding the keyboard layout settings directly to GDM's configuration file
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
[daemon]
DefaultSession=gnome
XKBLayout=fr
XKBVariant=bepo_afnor

gdm3 reads /etc/gdm3/custom.conf for its configuration
ubuntu-report/internal/metrics/testdata/empty-fields/autologin/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
4. Check GDM's Environment Script
GDM load setting from /etc/X11/Xsession and other scripts in /etc/X11/Xsession.d
Edit and add:
sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/00-keyboard.conf
setxkbmap fr bepo_afnor
5. Force Layout in Xsetup
Edit and add:
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/Xsetup
setxkbmap fr bepo_afnor
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
6. keyboardlayout XKB_DEFAULTS, setxkbmap

XKB options can be overridden by the tools provided by some desktop
environments such as GNOME and Plasma.

Xorg/Keyboard configuration
The XKB Configuration Guide
Permanently change xkb keybindings?
GDM defaults to en_US keyboard
7. dpkg-reconfigure keyboard gdm and debian keyboard layout(new and old posts) check for:

dpkg-reconfigure keyboard gdm
keyboard configuration gdm layout
dpkg-reconfigure change keyboard layout gdm

Different keyboard layout between login & gnome session
Debian wiki keyboard portal. This portal covers all aspects of configuring keyboards on Debian.
How do I change the login manager's keyboard layout?
Permanently change default language and keyboard settings - what am I missing?
Change keyboard layout without restarting system that applies to all virtual terminal instances
How to set default keyboard layout for GDM 3.16?
8. gnome control center, check for:

gnome control center gdm login screen layout
region and language gdm3
change keyboard layout gdm3 login screen


gnome-control-center is a graphical user interface to configure
various aspects of GNOME. When run without arguments, the shell
displays the overview, which shows all available configuration panels.
The overview allows to open individual panels by clicking on them.

SOLVED Different keyboard layout on very first Gnome login
How to change keyboard layout on the GNOME and Plasma login screens
Login screen doesn't show a keyboard layout switcher, prevents users from inputting passwords with a non-default character set
How to change the default keyboard for gnome?
How to install GNOME Control Center?
GNOME-CONTROL-CENTER doesn't show LOGIN section to set GDM keyboard layout
9. Settings in /etc/default/keyboard

Set system-wide keyboard settings that are also used by GDM. Change
the layout in /etc/default/keyboard for GDM.

10. Adjust Logind Configuration
Modify the keyboard layout settings in the logind configuration
/etc/systemd/logind.conf
11. Modify GDM Xsession Scripts
Edit the file /etc/gdm3/Xsession and explicitly set the layout for the login session.
12. localectl set-x11-keymap

localectl list-x11-keymap-models
localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts
localectl list-x11-keymap-variants [layout]
localectl list-x11-keymap-options


The system keyboard layout will be applied to GDM. You can use
localectl set-x11-keymap to specify the keyboard layout. See
Keyboard configuration in Xorg Setting keyboard layout for details.

From GDM - GNOME Display Manager
Setting keyboard layout

I had similar problem with turkish layout and solved with parts of the answer thank you
